# Plotting a 3d surface in Python from known values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array

I have a set of about 2000 files that look like: `10_20.txt`, `10_21.txt`, `10_21.txt`, ... ,`10_50.txt`, ... , `11.20.txt`, ... , `11.50.txt` , ... , `20_50.txt`

The first value in the file name, we'll call `x`, goes from 10-20 in steps of 1, and the second value in the file name, we'll call `y`, and goes from 20-50 in steps of 1.

Within these files, there is a load of values and another value I want to extract, which we'll call `z`.

I have written a program to cycle through the files and extract `z` from each file and add it to a list.

My question now is, if I have 2 `numpy` arrays that look like:

`x = np.arange(10,20,1)
 y = np.arange(20,50,1)`

and a `z` list that has ~2000 `floats` in it, what is the best way to plot how `z` depends on `x` and `y`? Is there standard way to do this?

I had been thinking it would be best to extract `x`, `y` and `z` from a file, and add them to a multidimensional array. If this is the case could anyone point me in the right direction of how to extract the `x` and `y` values out of the file name.

Comment: I don't understand what you have in mind; `x`, `y` and `z` are of different length, so what exactly do you want to plot? How do you define "depends"?

Comment: it appears that x and y connect to the filenames and these files have content you want to plot.  can you show the contents ?  is there more than one z value per file?

Comment: Each z value is contained within a file that has the x and y value in the title name .  The only thing in the file that I want to plot is the z value, which I have extracted all into a big list. This has resulted in different sized arrays , but in reality each value of x and y have a specific z value they map to , so all array lengths should be the same. I am asking how best to approach this

Comment: @ShpielMeister , the files are big text files containing molecular orbital calculations , the only value that is relevant in there is an energy, which I have extracted for each file into a list. So more specifically, x and y specify a molecular geometry , and z gives the energy. I want to see how the energy varies as we go through x and y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a ready function, say `read_z_from_file(filename)`, that returns the `z`-value contained in the file, you could go about it like this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10,20,1, dtype = np.int)
y = np.arange(20,50,1, dtype = np.int)
z = np.zeros((x.shape[0],y.shape[0]))

for i,x0 in enum(x):
   for j,y0 in enum(y):
      filename = '{}_{}.txt'.format(x0,y0)
      z[i,j] = read_z_from_file(filename)
```

You can then visualise `z` with `imshow` or `matshow` from `matplotlib`. For instance:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fix,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(z)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT**:

To respond to the questions of the OP, there is a multitude of ways to visualise your data. `imshow` and `matshow` do both about the same thing, but differ in the display details. Additionally, you can, among many others, produce contour plots or 3d surfaces. It depends a lot on what you want to see. Anyway, assuming that the code above does what you want, I show below some code that uses four different methods to display the same example data. You can find out more about these different methods with pythons in-built `help()` function and, of course, the [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/index.html) and [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/) documentation pages.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D ##for the 3d surface plot
from matplotlib import cm

#non-integer spacing of the coordinates
x = np.linspace (10, 20, 15)
y = np.linspace (20, 50, 70)

#gridding the coordinates
xm, ym = np.meshgrid(x,y)

#example data
z = np.exp(-( 0.1*(xm-12)**2 + 0.05*(ym-40)**2 ) )

#opening a figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))

#matshow:
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
res = ax1.matshow(
    z,
    origin = 'lower',
    aspect = 'auto',
    extent=[x[0],x[-1],y[0],y[-1]],
    )
fig.colorbar(res)
ax1.set_title('matshow', y=1.1)

#imshow
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
res = ax2.imshow(
    z,
    origin = 'lower',
    aspect = 'auto',
    extent=[x[0],x[-1],y[0],y[-1]],
    )
fig.colorbar(res)
ax2.set_title('imshow')


#contourf
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
res = ax3.contourf(xm,ym,z)
fig.colorbar(res)
ax3.set_title('contourf')

#3d surface
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224, projection='3d')
res = ax4.plot_surface(
    xm,ym,z,
    cmap = cm.viridis,
    antialiased=False
)
fig.colorbar(res, pad = 0.1)
ax4.set_title('3d surface')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The final plot looks like this:

[image: the result of the above given code]

Comment: Thanks, is there any easy way to modify this if I now have floats? E.g. if it's now x= 20.1, y = 50.2. As then the z[i,j] wouldnt work would it?

Comment: Yes, it would still work, because the 'i,j` are just the indices of the `numpy` array, but it would probably not be the best way to visualise your data anymore -- especially if your `x` and `y` are not equally spaced. There are, however, other possibilities like `contour` and `contourf` and `3d` surface plots. If you tell me exactly what you have and want, I can give you a more precise answer.

Comment: Note that there was a small mistake in the code I gave -- it's corrected now.

Comment: Ok, if I have `z` as a `91x25` matrix, `x` as a `1x91` array and `y` as a `1x25` array, with `z[i,j]` giving the value of `z` at `x[i], y[j]`, what would you suggest the best way to visualise this is ?

Comment: @loolipop please have a look at the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use x and y as coordinates and put a dot sized for the energy z.

a table would work as well, since you haven't stated that x and y geometries have any numeric purpose other than as lablels.